# Deducing Multiple Parameter Packs

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, templates, variadic-functions

## Background

I'm trying to write some template functions for a template-only unit test library, specifically for Qt.

## Problem

In this library, I have a variadic template that receives a variable amount of objects and functors (Qt5 Signals actually), always paired next to each other, as in `QObject, signal, etc...` then desirably followed by a variable amount of signal arguments.

## Desired Solution

```
// implementation.h

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Sargs, typename... Fargs>
void test_signal_daisy_chain(T* t,  void(T::*t_signal)(Fargs...), 
                             U* u,  void(U::*u_signal)(Fargs...), 
                             Sargs... sargs, 
                             Fargs... fargs) {...}

// client.cpp

test_signal_daisy_chain(object, &Object::signal1, 
                        object, &Object::signal2, 
                        object, &Object::signal3, 
                        1, 2, 3); // where the signals are defined as void(Object::*)(int, int, int)
```

Where `Fargs...` corresponds to both the parameters in `t_signal` and `u_signal` as well as the arguments to pass to this function for testing, and `Sargs...` corresponds to a variable amount of `QObject` and signal member functions (`void(T::*)(Fargs...)`) to emit for the express purpose of testing.

Unsurprisingly I get "no matching function" due to "template argument deduction/substitution failed", and my ClangCodeModel plugin warns me that 6 arguments were expected, where 8 were given.

## Working (ugly) solution

```
// implementation.h
template <typename... Fargs>
struct wrapper
{
    template <typename T, typename U, typename... Sargs>
    void test_signal_daisy_chain(Fargs... fargs, 
                                 T* t,  void(T::*t_signal)(Fargs...), 
                                 U* u,  void(U::*u_signal)(Fargs...), 
                                 Sargs... sargs) {...}

// client.cpp

wrapper<int, int, int>::test_signal_daisy_chain(1, 2, 3, 
                                                object, &Object::signal1,
                                                object, &Object::signal2,
                                                object, &Object::signal3);
```

I'm not content with having to explicitly define the variable function arguments at both the beginning of the function call and in the wrapper template type parameters. In fact, I was initially surprised that the could not be deduced simply by the fact that they were to match the variable arguments of the functors. I'm open to using wrapper functions as opposed to wrapper classes, as I already have a detail namespace set up which I'm willing to get messy for in order to provide a clean and user-friendly API.

***Note:*** signal arguments can be anywhere from primitives to user-defined types to POD structs to template classes, all of variable length.

***Edit 1***: c++11 is a hard requirement so you can leave >c++11 features in your answer as long as they have some c++11 workaround, i.e. `auto...` is easy to fix, `auto myFunction = []() constexpr {...};` much less so. If using `if constexpr` instead of a recursive `template <std::size_t>` helper function saves space and provides for a more succinct, complete, and future-proof answer, then please opt for whichever standard you deem best.

Comment: How would you like to delimit `Sargs` from `Fargs` in your desired solution?

Comment: Sargs should be split up by T (which in retrospect should inherit QObject), and another void(T::*)(Fargs). I need to iterate through them recursively so I end up calling it again with `test_signal_daisy_chain(u, u_signal, sargs..., fargs...)`. In hindsight I will probably need to declare `F f, Fargs... fargs` in my parameters so my expansion works.

Comment: The only way I see it working as-is is a signature `void test(T *t, void (T::*t_signal)(Fargs...), U*u, void (U::*u_signal)(Fargs...), Args... args)`, and then packing `Args` in a type-tuple, and operating on that to extract the `Sargs` types (by cutting off `Fargs` off the end) and the additional object-signal pairs, if any. If you plan any overloads, this won't work of course.

Comment: @KubaOber I agree, I think the only solution that will give me a nice clean front-end API is going to require a bit of work with tuples. I'm probably going to start working on an implementation of my own, but if you have an answer that 
1. has a style like `method(Object, ptr, Object, ptr, .../* variable amount of "Object, ptr", Fargs...)`
and 
2.does not require explicit type declarations or wrapper arguments,
then I'd be more than happy to look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach is to pack the parameters into a tuple at the beginning, and pass the tuple to `test_signal_daisy_chain_impl`:

```
template < typename... Fargs, 
          typename T, typename... Sargs>
void test_signal_daisy_chain_impl(const std::tuple<Fargs...> & fargs, 
                                  T* t, void(T::*t_signal)(Fargs...),
                                  Sargs &&... sargs)
{
    // apply unpacks the tuple
    std::apply([&](auto ...params) 
               {
                   (t->*t_signal)(params...);
               }, fargs);

    // Although packed into the tuple, the elements in
    // the tuple were not removed from the parameter list,
    // so we have to ignore a tail of the size of Fargs.
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Sargs) > sizeof...(Fargs))
       test_signal_daisy_chain_impl(fargs, std::forward<Sargs>(sargs)...);
}

// Get a tuple out of the last I parameters
template <std::size_t I, typename Ret, typename T, typename... Qargs>
Ret get_last_n(T && t, Qargs && ...qargs)
{
    static_assert(I <= sizeof...(Qargs) + 1, 
                  "Not enough parameters to pass to the signal function");
    if constexpr(sizeof...(Qargs)+1  == I)
       return {std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<Qargs>(qargs)...};
    else
       return get_last_n<I, Ret>(std::forward<Qargs>(qargs)...);
}    

template <typename T, typename... Fargs, 
          typename... Qargs>
void test_signal_daisy_chain(T* t, void(T::*t_signal)(Fargs...),
                             Qargs&&... qargs)
{
    static_assert((sizeof...(Qargs) - sizeof...(Fargs)) % 2 == 0,
                  "Expecting even number of parameters for object-signal pairs");
    if constexpr ((sizeof...(Qargs) - sizeof...(Fargs)) % 2 == 0) {
        auto fargs = get_last_n<sizeof...(Fargs), std::tuple<Fargs...>>(
                                 std::forward<Qargs>(qargs)...);
        test_signal_daisy_chain_impl(fargs, t, t_signal, 
                                     std::forward<Qargs>(qargs)...);
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
class Object {
public:
    void print_vec(const std::vector<int> & vec)
    {
        for (auto elem: vec) std::cout << elem << ", ";
    }
    void signal1(const std::vector<int> & vec) 
    { 
        std::cout << "signal1(";
        print_vec(vec);
        std::cout << ")\n";
    }
    void signal2(const std::vector<int> & vec) 
    { 
        std::cout << "signal2(";
        print_vec(vec);
        std::cout << ")\n";
    }
    void signal_int1(int a, int b) 
    { std::cout << "signal_int1(" << a << ", " << b << ")\n"; }
    void signal_int2(int a, int b) 
    { std::cout << "signal_int2(" << a << ", " << b << ")\n"; }
    void signal_int3(int a, int b) 
    { std::cout << "signal_int3(" << a << ", " << b << ")\n"; }
};

int main()
{
   Object object;
   test_signal_daisy_chain(&object, &Object::signal1,
                           &object, &Object::signal2 ,
                           std::vector{1,2,3});
   test_signal_daisy_chain(&object, &Object::signal_int1,
                           &object, &Object::signal_int2 ,
                           &object, &Object::signal_int3,
                           1,2);
}
```

---

### Edit 1

Since C++11 is a hard constraint, there is a much uglier solution, based on the same principles. Things like `std::apply` and `std::make_index_sequence` have to be implemented. Overloading is used instead of `if constexpr(....)` :

```
template <std::size_t ...I>
struct indexes
{
    using type = indexes;
};

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t ...I>
struct make_indexes
{
    using type_aux = typename std::conditional<
                    (N == sizeof...(I)),
                    indexes<I...>,
                    make_indexes<N, I..., sizeof...(I)>>::type;
    using type = typename type_aux::type;
};

template <typename Tuple, typename T, typename Method, std::size_t... I>
void apply_method_impl(
    Method t_signal, T* t, const Tuple& tup, indexes<I...>)
{
    return (t->*t_signal)(std::get<I>(tup)...);
}

template <typename Tuple, typename T, typename Method>
void apply_method(const Tuple & tup, T* t, Method t_signal)
{
      apply_method_impl(
        t_signal, t, tup,
        typename make_indexes<
             std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>::type{});
}

template < typename... Fargs,  typename... Sargs>
typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Fargs) == sizeof...(Sargs)), void>::type 
test_signal_daisy_chain_impl(const std::tuple<Fargs...> & , 
                             Sargs &&...)
{}

template < typename... Fargs, 
          typename T, typename... Sargs>
void test_signal_daisy_chain_impl(const std::tuple<Fargs...> & fargs, 
                                  T* t, void(T::*t_signal)(Fargs...),
                                  Sargs &&... sargs)
{
    apply_method(fargs, t, t_signal);

    // Although packed into the tuple, the elements in
    // the tuple were not removed from the parameter list,
    // so we have to ignore a tail of the size of Fargs.
    test_signal_daisy_chain_impl(fargs, std::forward<Sargs>(sargs)...);
}

// Get a tuple out of the last I parameters
template <std::size_t I, typename Ret, typename T, typename... Qargs>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Qargs)+1  == I, Ret>::type
get_last_n(T && t, Qargs && ...qargs)
{
    return Ret{std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<Qargs>(qargs)...};
}    

template <std::size_t I, typename Ret, typename T, typename... Qargs>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Qargs)+1  != I, Ret>::type
get_last_n(T && , Qargs && ...qargs)
{
    static_assert(I <= sizeof...(Qargs) + 1, "Not enough parameters to pass to the singal function");
    return get_last_n<I, Ret>(std::forward<Qargs>(qargs)...);
}    

template <typename T, typename... Fargs, 
          typename... Qargs>
void test_signal_daisy_chain(T* t, void(T::*t_signal)(Fargs...),
                             Qargs&&... qargs)
{
    static_assert((sizeof...(Qargs) - sizeof...(Fargs)) % 2 == 0,
                  "Expecting even number of parameters for object-signal pairs");
    auto fargs = get_last_n<sizeof...(Fargs), std::tuple<Fargs...>>(
                             std::forward<Qargs>(qargs)...);
    test_signal_daisy_chain_impl(fargs, t, t_signal, 
                                     std::forward<Qargs>(qargs)...);
}
```

---

### Edit 2

It is possible to avoid runtime recursion by storing all parameters in a tuple. The following `test_signal_daisy_chain_flat()` does exactly that, while retaining the same interface as `test_signal_daisy_chain()`:

```
template <typename Fargs, typename Pairs, std::size_t ...I>
void apply_pairs(Fargs && fargs, Pairs && pairs, const indexes<I...> &)
{
    int dummy[] = {
        (apply_method(std::forward<Fargs>(fargs),
                      std::get<I*2>(pairs),
                      std::get<I*2+1>(pairs)),
         0)...
    };
    (void)dummy;
}
template <typename T, typename... Fargs, 
          typename... Qargs>
void test_signal_daisy_chain_flat(T* t, void(T::*t_signal)(Fargs...),
                                  Qargs&&... qargs)
{
    static_assert((sizeof...(Qargs) - sizeof...(Fargs)) % 2 == 0,
                  "Expecting even number of parameters for object-signal pairs");
    auto fargs = get_last_n<sizeof...(Fargs), std::tuple<Fargs...>>(
                             std::forward<Qargs>(qargs)...);
    std::tuple<T*, void(T::*)(Fargs...), const Qargs&...> pairs{
        t, t_signal, qargs...};
    apply_pairs(fargs, pairs,
                typename make_indexes<(sizeof...(Qargs) - sizeof...(Fargs))/2>
                ::type{});
}
```

**Caveats**:

1. Not asserting that parameter pairs match. The compiler simply fails to compile (possibly deep in recursion).
2. The types of the parameters passed to the function are deduced from the signature of the first function, regardless of the types of the trailing parameters - the trailing parameters are converted to the required types.
3. All functions are required to have the same signature.

Comment: I apologze for not making myself clearer, `Fargs` for each function (pointer) is equal, i.e. signal1, signal2, and signal3 all have the same signature, and we will be testing their connections by also passing in data according to `Fargs`. For example, if the function signature if `void(T::*)(int, int, int)`, We pass in three integers for our `Fargs`. `Sargs` Corresponds to a variable amount of QObjects and their signals, which are member function pointers in this case, such that Sargs is unpacked like `QObject, fptr, ..., Fargs...)` respectively.

Comment: @jfhcs Trivial to fix, but I'm not near a computer and can't validate. Fixed without testing.

Comment: No rush, I'm ultimately looking for a solution that fits 2 criteria:

Comment: 1. has a style like method(Object, ptr, Object, ptr, .../* variable amount of "Object, ptr", Fargs...) and 
2.does not require explicit type declarations or wrapper arguments
(Note: ran out of time to edit my above comment, sorry)

Comment: @jfhcs made major changes to match the clarified requirements. The function that accepts the tuple has now `_impl` in its name

Comment: This looks really nice my friend. I tested it out and it (obviously) works well, the only caveat being that I had to make `get_last_n` return a `std::tuple`. It complained about the `initializer_list`, which surprised me because I only used integral types in my test cases. Regardless, I am using it mainly for ~100 types which have no explicit move or copy constructors, and after testing on the first few they seems to be copying fine. The most important thing to me is that it moves rvalues correctly when passed as parameters (although I'll mostly be using constexpr arrays for my data).

Comment: I'll be accepting this tomorrow if noone else comes up with another answer. I'm also going to give myself the exercise of trying to make overloads where I can deduce the chain, i.e `...daisy_chain(object1, &Object::signal1, &Object::signal2, obejct2, &Object::signal3, 1, 2, 3)` and so forth and so on, although I'll lose out on my static asserts. Your caveats are actually good for me, as Qt signals and slots should faill to compile if incompatible. None of my types have conversion so thats good as well. If you'd like to take a go at 4 I'd be interested in seeing it but I have a working solution

Comment: @jfhcs I have added a non-recursive variant at the end of the answer named `test_signal_daisy_chain_flat`. I used a new name to avoid confusion, but basically it has the same interface as `test_signal_daisy_chain`.

Answer (score 4):

```
template<class T>
struct tag_t { using type=T; };
template<class Tag>
using type_t = typename Tag::type;

template<class T>
using no_deduction = type_t<tag_t<T>>;

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Sargs, typename... Fargs>
void test_signal_daisy_chain(
  T* t, void(T::*t_signal)(Sargs...),
  U* u, void(U::*u_signal)(Fargs...),
  no_deduction<Sargs>... sargs,
  no_deduction<Fargs>... fargs)
```

I assume the `Fargs...` in `t_signal` was a typo, and was supposed to be `Sargs`.

If not, you are in trouble.  There is no rule that "earlier deduction beats later deduction".

One thing you can do in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) is to have a function returning a function object:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename... Fargs>
auto test_signal_daisy_chain(
  T* t, void(T::*t_signal)(Fargs...),
  U* u, void(U::*u_signal)(Fargs...),
  no_deduction<Fargs>... fargs
) {
  return [=](auto...sargs) {
    // ...
  };
}
```

Then use looks like:

```
A a; B b;
test_signal_daisy_chain( &a, &A::foo, &b, &B::bar, 1 )('a', 'b', 'c');
```

doing this in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) is possible with a manually written function object.

Comment: My apologies, Fargs.. in t_signal should match the parameters of u_signal, and Sargs corresponds to a variable amount of QObject and member function pairs. I'll update for clairty.

Comment: @jfhcs I think I covered that case.  I had to swap the order of `fargs` and `sargs`

Comment: I don't seem to be having any luck with my test cases. Additionally, one of my hard requirements for this is that It follows the Qt conventions of having `QObject, functor, QObject, functor` much like the `QObject::connect` function. Thank you for being patient though I appreciate the help.

Comment: @jfhcs You are right, that doesn't work.  Alternative workaround added.